# How to invoke Dynamically a method of an instantied object in c#

Tags: c#, methods, system.reflection, non-static

I want to create a method that invokes a public method, of an instantied class, dynamically (using reflect).

First, I have my class:

```
namespace NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes.NFSeWeb
{    
    public class Service
    {
        public string IdService { get; set; }
        public string Name {get; set; }

        public getKey()
        {
          return IdService + Name;      
        } 
    }
}
```

The method "getKey" will be in a few classes.

Ok till there... but I am creating a function that returns the value from function **getKey** of an object dynamically instantied.

I have a function that I will pass an Object as parameter:

```
internal static string getValorDaClasse(object valor)
{
    if (valor.ToString().Contains("NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes"))
    {
        Type myType = Type.GetType(valor.ToString());
        object myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

        //Invoking a non-static method (How to invoke a non static method??)

        return (string)myType.InvokeMember("getKey", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, myObj, new object[] { valor });
     }
     else
         return valor.ToString();
}
```

When I try to do that (get the value from the method "**getKey**"... I receive the following exception: **Method 'NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes.NFSeWeb.Service.getKey' not found.**

All the best!

Comment: Your error message and class definitions don't match up. Where does `getChave` come from? And what is the class `Servico`?

Comment: sorry @gunr2171 .. I've fixed that mistake. getChave == getKey and Servico means Service (in Portuguese).

Comment: `The method "getKey" will be in a few classes.` Wouldn't it be easier to define an interface with a `GetKey` method and have those classes implement that method? Then your `GetValorDaClasse()` method can take that interface as a parameter and invoke the method.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange, would be more easier, for sure, but, that is not the situation

Comment: @DanielLex Well can you explain what it is that you're exactly trying to do? Right now you're creating a new instance of whatever object is passed to the `getValorDaClasse()` using `Activator` without passing the original values to the new instance. So in this case, a call to `getKey` will in fact return an empty string. I think you might need to rethink your design.

Comment: For what I see you are passing an argument when invoking the method, but the method have no args.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange... the function getValorDaClasse should return the value from the "getKey" method of the object passed as parameter in the function getValorDaClasse

Comment: @DanielLex But it doesn't, right? As I said, you are creating a new instance of the object without passing the original values to it.

Comment: Please consider marking answer and upvoting those answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer is this:

```
return (string)myType.InvokeMember("getChave", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance, null, myObj, null);
```

where "getChave" is the name of the function that I want to call.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `InvokeMember` incorrectly.  Notice the last parameter of `InvokeMember`, You are not passing anything into `getKey`, so null is appropriate there. Also, the binding flags werent allowing you to get the proper method.

```
return (string)myType.InvokeMember("getKey", 
                                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod|
                                         BindingFlags.Public | 
                                         BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | 
                                         BindingFlags.Instance, 
                                    null, 
                                    myObj,
                                    null);
```

Your Service method:

```
namespace NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes.NFSeWeb
{
    public class Service
    {
        public string IdService { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string getKey()
        {
            return IdService + Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Your calling method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mystring = getValorDaClasse("NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes.NFSeWeb.Service");
    }

    public static string getValorDaClasse(object valor)
    {
        if (valor.ToString().Contains("NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes"))
        {
            Type myType = Type.GetType(valor.ToString());
            object myObj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

            //Invoking a non-static method (How to invoke a non static method??)

            return (string)myType.InvokeMember("getKey", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod|BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance, null, myObj, null);
        }
        else
            return valor.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the differences are in this code? Only after looking at it for 2 minutes did I see a change in the last parameter for `InvokeMember`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error: Method 'NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes.NFSeWeb.Servico.getKey' not found.

Comment: tell me more about this `valor` object, my assumption is that its value is `NFSe.Classes.Models.Classes.NFSeWeb.Service`.  Is that correct?

Comment: The clue might be in the error.  Everything that you've given here says that your class is called `Service`, but your error says `.Servico.getKey`  is there a typo in the value of `valor`?

Comment: I can run all the code that i posted for you in a console app w/o error.  So, there is something that you are not showing us.

Comment: @paqogomez, now, I runned fine.. but, there is still a problem... the value passed as parameter in the function getValorDaClasse is an object... I would like to get the result of the function "getKey" from the object passed as parameter...

Comment: @paqogomez .. the problem is that I am instantiating a new empty object, and invoking the "getKey" function.. that won't return result.. because the object instatied is null... I would like to get the result of the getKey function of the object that I passed as parameter in the getValorDaClasse.

Comment: Oh, so where are you going to set the values for `IdService` and `Name`?

Comment: And how are you instantiating `valor`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate, refer the method with the delegate and pass it as a parameter..

Let me show you a simple example for using delegates..

```
namespace DelimiterStage1
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate();
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MyDelegate delg = new MyDelegate(catchup);

            new Form2(delg).Show();
        }

        private void catchup()
        {
            label1.Text = "Gotcha!";
        }
    }
}
```

Form2 --

```
namespace DelimiterStage1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(MyDelegate delgt)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            delgate_Form2 = delgt;
        }

        MyDelegate delgate_Form2;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            delgate_Form2();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No one really uses plain delegates these days, except for events. `Action` and `Func` are more flexible.